# What do you call the pointy parts of a text bubble that's not the tail?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

What do you call the pointy parts of a text bubble that's not the tail? Here, in the image, we see three pointy things protruding out of the text bubble on the four "sides" of some of the text bubbles, is there a particular name for them? I know the other pointy part is called the tail, but I am wondering what the three pointy things on all four "sides" are called.

Comment: FWIW the terms "speech bubble"/"thought bubble" are pretty standard ("text bubble" seems fine, too), but I don't think there's much agreement among laypeople about what to call any subpart of them.

Comment: Not sure what they're called, but the obvious implication is that someone is talking over a radio connection (or equivalent).  The 2nd panel in particular is unusual as there's one spikey bubble without a tail and one with, since we're seeing the ship from the outside, and that the pilot in panels 1 and 3 is the one talking over a radio in that instance, while the ones without a tail are from someone "off-screen" as it were.

Comment: (for subtitles) "*What is used to indicate a [voice over](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice-over#Creative_device)?* Simply use parentheses next to the character name and write “(V.O.)”" or, I've seen *just* brackets - but it's a comic with unlimited font potential, so you can use a ***VO* bubble**, the kind with pointy things, w/e you call them doesn't matter; important part is what it indicates : "voices not directly connected to the people seen on the screen".

Comment: IIRC, the extra bits are in general typographically classified as "decoration".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would use the word "**spike**". (And in this particular case **triple spike**.)

Here are some links:

[Metal speech bubble with spikes](https://www.dreamstime.com/metal-speech-bubble-speech-bubble-spikes-d-rendering-image106746484)

[Wooden speech bubble with spikes](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Wooden-Speech-Bubble-Spikes-Decorative/dp/B083LXT6L1)

[Google Images search result](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22text%20bubble%20spikes%22&biw=1280&bih=555&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&vet=1&fir=I-S-7Q2tLBq9vM%252Cf25OoCd8_W7q3M%252C_%253BH_Fguk49wlfyIM%252Cf25OoCd8_W7q3M%252C_%253BIqVHw4W8qQhI0M%252Cf25OoCd8_W7q3M%252C_%253B9qe5KX2g2gDpLM%252Cf25OoCd8_W7q3M%252C_%253BL9060ZVGY13iFM%252Cf25OoCd8_W7q3M%252C_%253BIhIiRzZFIHAXYM%252Cf25OoCd8_W7q3M%252C_%253B96MvfDOJTfCnpM%252Cf25OoCd8_W7q3M%252C_%253Be3mnc4wEkWnAZM%252CIEK49-QL_XKAzM%252C_%253B-Iq9Qi6sq7LB1M%252Cf25OoCd8_W7q3M%252C_%253BFERLCEVVCHcTbM%252CIEK49-QL_XKAzM%252C_&usg=AI4_-kR4meIDADKU0zhI5Rxch-j7gEXuMg&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjE5-SV3cP4AhX9gP0HHV7bA2AQ9QF6BAgLEAE#imgrc=H_Fguk49wlfyIM)

Comment: +1 because the edit history shows you were the first to mention **spike** and **triple spike** in their answer, and I'm upvoting that.

Answer (score 15):

It represents the radio transmission of someone talking to the character using *spikes*, in this case a **triple spike**. Usually it is for **announcements** or **sound effects**. I don't think there is an official name for the one you have shown, but it is close to other examples.

[image]

[Source](https://www.animeoutline.com/how-to-draw-manga-speech-bubbles/)

Answer (score 3):

As a direct description of their appearance I agree with @PPH, however as @DialFrost points out, there are other levels of understanding.

An artist is likely to refer to any changes (and just the changes) to the standard speech bubble as "Decorations", and any consistent set of decorations as a "Style".

The writer might additionally refer to individual styles as "Indicators" or "Modes", but it's more common for the artist to simply read "character X yells help" and apply the *yell* **style**, which consists of the *three spikes* **decoration**, with the **text** *help*,  with the **tail** pointing to *character x*.